# ¿Cómo quitar duplicados en sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
 CB.Codigo,
 A.Articulo,
 CB.SubCuenta as 'Opcion',
 A.Descripcion1 as 'Descripcion',
 CB.Cantidad,
 CB.Unidad,
 A.Tipo as 'Serie/Lote',
 CB.Referencia,
 CB.Marca,
 A.Observaciones,
 AC.CostoPromedio
FROM CB
 JOIN Art as A on A.Articulo = CB.Cuenta
 JOIN ArtCosto as AC on AC.Articulo = A.Articulo
```

En esta consulta cuando hago el join con `ArtCosto` me duplica 3 veces los registros por cada articulo, veo que muchos ocupan este método para `eliminar`:

```
DELETE T
FROM
(
SELECT *
, DupRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY key_value
          ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
        )
FROM original_table
) AS T
WHERE DupRank > 1
```

a mi no me gustaría eliminar el registro, solo quiero mostrar 1 en vez de los 3 que salen, se puede realizar? o forzoso es borrar el registro?

Comment: ¿Por que haces un join a `ArtCosto` si no estas usando ninguno de sus datos?

Comment: Si, si voy a utilizar varios datos, nada mas que en el ejemplo no lo coloque por que se haría muy grande.

Comment: Justamente sabiendo los datos que vas a usar se te puede sugerir alguna agregación.

Comment: Edité la pregunta y añadí un campo que si requiero de ella como ejemplo.

Comment: Bien `AC.CostoPromedio` tiene un valor que se repite en las 3 filas? o es diferente? y si es diferente, cual de los 3 posibles valores es el que buscas mostrar?

Comment: No, no es diferente

Comment: Te recomiendo investigar sobre el uso del HAVING y GROUP BY. Si aplicas bien ambas puedes solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Es probable que tu tabla `ArticuloCosto` tenga un rango de fechas por el cual puedas identificar el costo del artículo en una fecha determinada. Sin embargo, sin estructura de las tablas es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Un buen ejemplo que podrías incluir en la pregunta tendría una o dos filas de `CB`, las correspondientes de `Art` y de `ArtCosto` con un ejemplo de la salida que quieres lograr con exactamente esos datos. Otra posibilidad es publicar la estructura de las tablas y una descripción completa, en lenguaje coloquial, de lo que buscas, siempre con la mentalidad del [mcve]. Sin alguna de estas cosas, como ya han dicho antes, es imposible ayudarte.